# how to use comparison test for improper integral?

Tags: improper-integrals

I should determine whether this is a convergent or divergent integral.
i need to use the comparison test but i don't know where to start.
there is a method to find the integral we need to compare to? how to start?

$$
 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{sinx}{x^2}dx
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In our interval, $\sin x\ge \frac{x}{2}$.